# How do I get the full error message from my Node and Express server on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express route that returns a 400 status and an error message. I want to alert the full error message on the client-side, but the alert only says "Object object" when I alert it. I inspected that object and I don't see the full error message that I see logged to my terminal from the server.

On the server the error message says, "djhbf is not defined" because I typed in some random characters to throw an error message. On the client-side, the object has some properties, but none of them contain the error message "djhbf is not defined". The closest thing to an error message is, "status-text: bad request". How do I retrieve the actual error message "djhbf is not defined" on the client-side?

Here is my server.js code which sends the error message in its catch block of a promise:

```
app.post('/sendEmails', function(req, res, next) {
  axios.get(FEED_URL)
    .then(data => {
      let jobs = data.data.jobs;
      fetchClients(jobs, 'email').then(() => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json(err);
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Here is the client-side code which alerts the error:

```
sendEmails() {
    axios.post("/sendEmails")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          emailsSent: true,
          smsSent: false
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

*Updated*

This is not an express issue. `axios` decorates the error object. You just need to change your client side console.log to this: `console.log(err.response.data);`

You will also need to update your server side logic since you are using `axios` on both sides. Try `res.status(400).json({msg: 'There was a problem with your request'});`

If that works you'll just need to drill down in the `err` object on the server side to see what you want to send back to the client.

See the [Error Handling](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors) section of the `axios` docs.

Comment: The error message produced by the server is an object. How do I handle such an object so that it's valid json?

Comment: I tried this: 

res.status(404).json({ status: 404, message: JSON.stringify(err)});

But message still comes back as an empty object.

Comment: On the client-side, there is no response property on the "err" object actually. It looks like this: Object {data: Object, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Object, config: Object…}

The data property of the error object only contains the javascript object prototype, not my message.

Comment: I updated it again. I think you should try hardcoding a response to see what you get, then inspect the server side error object in the `catch` to decide what exactly you want to send back to the client.